# Add type-safety for nested object-type

Tags: typescript, object, types, autocomplete

I want to build a translation-library, ideally while maintaining full type-safety. This is what I have so far:

```
// Want to add translations for a new language?
// Just add "| 'gr'"
type Lang = "de" | "en";

type Fields = {
  // We can define sub-entries for each new context. history, orderManagement,
  // vehicleDetails... whatever makes sense.
  history: {
    historyEntry: string;
    locationChanged: string;
    manuallyCreated: string;
  };
  orderManagement: {
    // If there is a new string to translate, we add a new field of type string
    order: string;
  };
};

// This is the "root-type" that binds each lang to the fields-object
type Translations = {
  [key in Lang]: Fields;
};

// If you delete one single entry, you will get an error.
// The type "Translations" makes sure that you don't forget
// a single field
const translations: Translations = {
  de: {
    history: {
      locationChanged: "Standort geändert",
      manuallyCreated: "Manuell erstellt",
    },
    orderManagement: {
      order: "Auftrag",
    },
  },
  en: {
    history: {
      locationChanged: "Location Changed",
      manuallyCreated: "Manually Created",
    },
    orderManagement: {
      order: "Order",
    },
  },
};

// TODO: How can this be more type-safe?
export const getTranslations = (lang: Lang, context: string, field: string) => {
  return translations[lang][context][field];
}
```

how can I refactor the `Fields`-type, so that the `getTranslations` function is more typesafe?

Right now I could call `getTranslations` like this:

```
const foo = getTranslations("de", "bar", "baz");
```

without noticing the error at build-time / in the text-editor. Making this more type-safe would also bring the benefit of enabling autocompletion in the text-editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to change the `Fields` you should instead make `getTranslations` generic to capture the context the user of `getTranslations` wants to get. YOu need to specify that this type parameter has to extend `keyof Fields`. You can then use an indexed type to type `field` to be one of the fields of the previously specified context:

```
export const getTranslations = <C extends keyof Fields>(lang: Lang, context: C, field: keyof Fields[C]) => {
  return translations[lang][context][field];
}

const t1 = getTranslations("de", "history", "locationChanged"); //ok
const t2 = getTranslations("de", "orderManagement", "locationChanged"); // error
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEHUEMDsBdVge1JAJqhAnGBnANpLAJaLQ6gBmimKo0ApgO6gHQDmArpG-QPwBQIUACkOOeGgwAiAD6gA5G0zyp-WAE8ADvVAAZGG1ABeUFNT0poOVPrQpAbn5qtOgGJF6eVORMBvfqCgQuA6AMYwoOYURAygOBwARgC0trCYHuRUNPSQoQAWdEygoaSw9AAesAB0oHlE4tTqADSg1OaYALIw3PQAtqlNAUFgAG70daF49AAi9LCQRHg4VSugjHmE9GM0vZAA1vTkOLbHVUN1DZjqAFyg-oGBeIjhxKQAwhvs9Ki34unsjgeoF20C4eDw6jemByZR+cTSMTYgNAAF9kW16J1ujx+nBbvcHkIAJIUBB5TE6eq0BjMP6IhDINK4AhlFqMHSSalFaKeDCIUkabTw-5sIaBDGYX4IgFDNH8OWCMAAFQuoCpsHJpkwiEQsCSgosZMIoASMW8oBy+RYBgZZJ0PK8OCSiASACt6KFYM4hUrsGQWSQyMY7kMANoHdRq6B6AwAXVu7l5OEcCuJpPUiA4kU8cx0pB0OERUwtcCuLQzWcYizwoB4EmjmO1mDOQhVOgNpl9zMIgZwll2ByOHGhRvgFcipHk8CydcVtEL7GLDtQ-BKZHgTP9PdIOFuXa3ryDfiG5nxYtq9SQVzPQMez230A+Bm+tykAGV5tBUNR4DwACdfpisBSIMt7AjAYIQlCMIvqYXSgp4NaYuIiHAaBDwouh4qYO08E9LisA3reEqvgAghwFBMmwIHnphsrobYRGBBcV43CGYFPC8gZPl8cJSLo96HqAPE8KgNFgSCkGQtCmx8fBUnCTJsLiRhWGtDhmJ4TiqRMQ8JGmAA8hpmAqYEdFmYMCr8BUmg-sUO6-nM+74A+PigAAPG8FqVLY5oRvyoCJo6AB8AAUrBsLc+jsC0a5lJUtxvC0y63P5pJBd4oZvLGACUxjBexoDQrAw7RpuLmHjgoYRbGoZxRUsC1cusYpk4a7iAgACMwZ1s5AY7qFZgWC0UgsY0IGmJxD4id8Ug5fYwyIHsq4OQgABMPVOX6FW9oN5gTVIEpaX0qQHVNh4zWJ83DBamBNkAA)

You can also make the second parameter be a `.` separated path to the field:

```
type Path<T> = keyof {
  [P in keyof T & string as `${P}.${keyof T[P] & string}`]: never
}
export const getTranslations = (lang: Lang, path: Path<Fields>) => {
  let [context, field] = path.split('.') as [keyof Fields, keyof Fields[keyof Fields]]
  return translations[lang][context][field];
}

const t1 = getTranslations("de", "history.locationChanged"); //ok
const t2 = getTranslations("de", "orderManagement.locationChanged"); // error
const t3 = getTranslations("de", "orderManagement.order"); //ok
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=57&ssc=64&pln=57&pc=55#code/PTAEHUEMDsBdVge1JAJqhAnGBnANpLAJaLQ6gBmimKo0ApgO6gHQDmArpG-QPwBQIUACkOOeGgwAiAD6gA5G0zyp-WAE8ADvVAAZGG1ABeUFNT0poOVPrQpAbn5qtOgGJF6eVORMBvfqCgQuA6AMYwoOYURAygOBwARgC0trCYHuRUNPSQoQAWdEygoaSw9AAesAB0oHlE4tTqADSg1OaYALIw3PQAtqlNAUFgAG70daF49AAi9LCQRHg4VSugjHmE9GM0vZAA1vTkOLbHVUN1DZjqAFyg-oGBeIjhxKQAwhvs9Ki34unsjgeoF20C4eDw6jemByZR+cTSMTYgNAAF9kW16J1ujx+nBbvcHkIAJIUBB5TE6eq0BjMP6IhDINK4AhlFqMHSSalFaKeDCIUkabTw-5sIaBDGYX4IgFDNH8OWCMAAFQuoCpsHJpkwiEQsCSgosZMIoASMW8oBy+RYBgZZJ0PK8OCSiASACt6KFYM4hUrsGQWSQyMY7kMANoHdRq6B6AwAXVu7l5OEcCuJpPUiA4kU8cx0pB0OERUwtcCuLQzWcYizwoB4EmjmO1mDOQhVOgNpl9zMIgZwll2ByOHGhRvgFcipHk8CydcVtEL7GLDtQ-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)

Comment: Great! This is exactly what I was looking for! I'm marking this as solved.
@titian-cernicova-dragomir any idea if I could somehow make this work with `"history.locationChanged"` instead of specifying the nested levels as two separate arguments? I think react-hook-form and react-i18next provide type-safety with dot-notation.

Comment: @TimHilt Added a version with path

Comment: legend! Thank you! Learned a lot today :)